# How to store Python 2.6 value in regedit

Tags: python, window

What information about Python 2.6 stored in the Windows registry, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE?  Where is it stored?

Somehow I lost it in my regedit and can't install a module. I googled it, but I can't find any answer, and I don't have an extra computer to try and many modules that I need for my school project is installed inside, so I don't want to take the risk to uninstall.

Comment: It sounds like you want a standalone regedit.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh, I found the solution by repairing the Python 2.6 installation.